# could not get expected Mapped result of array of objects in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have an issue when map the array of object.

`const currentYear = [{ value: 2021, label: 2021 }];`

I tried with this

```
<div className={styles.calendar_heading}>
          Calendar for Year{" "}
          {Object.keys(currentYear).map((item, index) => (
            <span className="input-label">{item}</span>
          ))}
 </div>
```

output
`Calendar for Year 0`

I expected `Calendar for Year 2021` as an output. What is the issue with my code?

Comment: currentYear isn’t an object right? So object keys won’t work with that. Why not just do map on currentYear directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `.map` to get it.

```js
const currentYear = [{
  value: 2021,
  label: 2021
}];


currentYear.map((item, index) => {
  console.log(item.value);
})
```

So the fixed code:

```
{currentYear.map((item, index) => (
   <span className="input-label">{item.value}</span>
))}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Object.keys(currentYear).map((item, index)`, you should use `currentYear.map((item, index) => ...`, since `currentYear` is already an array.

```
{currentYear.map((item, index) => (
  <span className="input-label">{item.label}</span>
))}
```